# Indy 10 Client Certificate: All in One .pem File?

Tags: openssl, c++builder, indy10

**tl;dr:**

Is there a way for TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL to use one .pem file that includes cert, root, and key for a client certificate?

---

**Details:**

A vendor partner requires us to use mTLS authentication. They furnished a certificate, which I exported (including my cert, the root cert, and the private key) in PEM format.

Then, I did some simple connectivity tests in PHP, using cURL.

**Note that I was able to use my all-inclusive .pem file.**

```
$the_url = 'https://example.com/post-to-me';
$xml_payload = '<foo>bar</foo>';
$headers = array( "Content-type: text/xml",
                  "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_payload),
                  "Connection: close" );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $the_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);            // Force curl_exec() to return server response string rather than true/false
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);                  // 10-second timeout
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'all-in-one-cert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'super-secret-password');

$result     = curl_exec($ch);
```

This yielded the expected result from the server, so I moved on to writing my C++ Builder code:

```
FHTTP               = new TIdHTTP( 0 );
FSSLIOHandlerSocket = new TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL( 0 );

FLogFile            = new TIdLogFile( 0 );
FLogFile->LogTime   = true;

FSSLIOHandlerSocket->Intercept                  = FLogFile;
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->IPVersion                  = Id_IPv4;
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->MaxLineAction              = maException;
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->SSLOptions->Mode           = sslmClient;
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->SSLOptions->CertFile       = "all-in-one-cert.pem";
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->SSLOptions->RootCertFile   = "all-in-one-cert.pem";
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->SSLOptions->KeyFile        = "all-in-one-cert.pem";
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->OnGetPassword              = GetPassWord;
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->SSLOptions->Method         = sslvTLSv1_2;

FHTTP->IOHandler            = FSSLIOHandlerSocket;
FHTTP->ConnectTimeout       = 10000;
FHTTP->ReadTimeout          = 60000;
FHTTP->MaxAuthRetries       = 0;
FHTTP->Request->ContentType = "text/xml";

TStringStream * MsgStream = new TStringStream();
TStringStream * RspStream = new TStringStream();

MsgStream->WriteString( "<foo>bar</foo>" );

FHTTP->Post( "https://example.com/post-to-me", MsgStream, RspStream );

long StreamSize     = RspStream->Size;
RspStream->Position = 0;
FResponse           = RspStream->ReadString( StreamSize ).Trim();
```

This resulted in the following OpenSSL error:

> Could not load certificate.
>   error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)

I also tried:

```
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->SSLOptions->CertFile       = "all-in-one-cert.pem";
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->OnGetPassword              = GetPassWord;
```

That yielded the same error.

I also tried using the .pfx certificate file:

```
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->SSLOptions->CertFile       = "all-in-one-cert.pfx";
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->OnGetPassword              = GetPassWord;
```

This allowed the certificate to load, but then resulted in a handshake failure on connection:

> Error connecting with SSL.
>   error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

I used Wireshark to verify that this handshake error occurred because 0 certificates were being passed into the handshake.

I resolved the issue by splitting the client certificate, root, and key into three separate files, like so:

```
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->SSLOptions->CertFile       = "cert-only.pem";
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->SSLOptions->RootCertFile   = "root-only.pem";
FSSLIOHandlerSocket->SSLOptions->KeyFile        = "key-only.pem";
```

Still, I am curious: Is there a way to do it with all three components in a single .pem file? Or am I missing something? I am new to this mTLS business, so please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: If you are using OpenSSL 1.0.2, the `CertFile` can be a single file containing a whole chain of certificates. But AFAIK, the `RootCertFile` and `KeyFile` must be separate files. The `RootCertFile` may contain multiple CA certificates, though.

Comment: Thanks, @RemyLebeau! I appreciate your time and expertise.